# Как настроить админку в Django чтобы не получать ошибок про обязательные поля

Tags: django, django-admin, model

У меня в моделях настроено задание значений по умолчанию и эти поля обязательные, но админка Django ругается на незаполненные обязательные поля.

Как быть чтобы оставить поля обязательными в бд, необязательными в админке для пользователя и задаваемыми по умолчанию моей функцией?

Или моя логика не сильно логичная? Жду вашего компетентного мнения.

(Django 2.1.5)

Comment: Если у поля в модели прописан `default`, то Django по умолчанию автоматически прописывает этот `default` в форме на странице в админке, и никаких незаполненных обязательных полей быть не может. Если у вас не прописывает, значит вы что-то сломали/отключили и покажите пример, демонстрирующий вашу проблему

Comment: @andreymal, `default` не прописывал, но прописал изменение в переопределённом методе сохранения. В `default` этот функционал не записать, там метод, который читает другие поля этой модели

Comment: А надо было прописывать `default` :) А на момент работы сохранения значения вроде бы уже должны существовать, так что в нём прописывать скорее всего неправильно (хотя я не знаю вашей точной задачи и могу ошибаться)

Comment: то есть прописать туда uuid.uuid4, потом его поменять при сохранении?

(оно ещё и уникально и там нужен метод, который читает другие поля этой модели)

Comment: Документация Django [предлагает](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)` — тогда поле вообще не будет видно в админке и автоматически заполнится при создании (уникальным значением, разумеется). Если нужно, чтобы UUID можно было прочитать после создания, можно его в `readonly_fields` в админке прописать

Comment: uuid можно и в default прописать, не в этом суть, я просто хочу заполнять уникальное обязательное поле `slug` по умолчанию сложной функцией, если пользователь не ввёл другой строки. админка агрится на повторяющиеся значения и на пустую строку

Comment: Если вы создаёте uuid (slug?) по каким-то особенным правилам, то возможно будет правильнее [создать свою ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) и уже тут прописать необязательность поля админки и сложную функцию для значения по умолчанию для модели, но лично я этим никогда не занимался и подробнее не подскажу

Comment: уникальные поля в админке в принципе реально заполнять по умолчанию?

Comment: у меня поле slug которое генерируется из заголовка текущей записи, поэтому его нельзя сгенерировать заранее

Comment: Разрешите сохранять поле пустым, а в модели напишите функцию `save()` в которой будет нужно вам поле заполняться нужным образом.

Если всё-таки хотите оставить поле обязательным к заполнению: воспользуйтесь сигналами (pre_save).

Comment: похоже, джанго в принципе не позволяет заполнять уникальные поля значением `None`, попробовал `slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, default=None)`, но админка всё равно жалуется на пустое поле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам

Решил проблему добавив параметр `blank=True`

```py
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
```

Админка не агрится на пустое поле и даёт сгенерировать `slug` при сохранении